# Silently call PHP-CLI script from PHP page

Tags: php, cron, command-line-interface

I have a number of PHP scripts that I run under PHP-CLI via cron jobs. All OK.

What I would like to do is, via a web page that I have already created, allow the user to manually run their own individual file by calling the .php file that contains their script (which is called via cron).

I already have the control panel and have a button where I want to be able to call the PHP script from, but I want it to be done 'silently' as the page contains data that I do not want them to see. Ideally I want to be able to call the PHP file and it run in the background and PHP-CLI.

So I guess my question is, can I execute a PHP-CLI script from a PHP page and have it execute without displaying any information to the user?

Answer (score 0):

I have since found this works.

```
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://URL/page.php"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, TRUE); // remove body 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); 
curl_exec($ch);
```